# WCF DataContract on Abstract base class and its Subclasses

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a monitoring app that receives processing updates from other applications via WCF. Previously the apps being monitored had one "update" class to send data to the monitoring app. Now I'm writing an abstract base class that looks like this

```
public abstract class Update
{
    public readonly DateTime TimeStamp;
    public readonly int      AppId;

    public Update()
    {
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        AppId = SomeMethodThatCalculatesId();
    }

    private int SomeMethodThatCalculatesId()
    {
        // my calculations ...
    }
}
```

Here's an example subclass

```
public class ProcessUpdate : Update
{
    public readonly string ProcessMessage;

    public ProcessUpdate(string processMessage) : base()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(processMessage))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("processMessage");
        }

        ProcessMessage = processMessage;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to send the monitoring app anything derived from `Update` and want to prevent Update from being instantiated, that's why it's abstract. I want one implementation for my AppId generation and for derived classes to not worry about it or alter it, that's why AppId is readonly.

Does `Update` require a `DataContract` attribute tag or is that only required for my subclasses? If that's the case, can I still  decorate `TimeStamp` and `AppId` with `DataMemeber` without `DataContract` and still access those properties in the monitoring app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the recommendation in WFC is to communicate via interfaces. In your case that would mean making `TimeStamp` and `AppId` properties of the interface (decorate that with `DataContract`) and decorating them with `DataMember`, then you should implement this interface in `Update`.

In the situation you are talking about, if you want to be able see `Update` objects over WCF then you need to decorate it with `DataContract` and if you want to be able to see the read only fields, then you need to decorate them with `DataMember`.

Comment: Ok, so if I get this right, Update and ProcessUpdate need DataContract. While IUpdate would need DataMember on its properties. Is that correct?

Comment: Or could I just decorate ProcessUpdate with DataContract since Update will never go over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the service with [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) to tell the client about the subclasses, which should make it work when you send things derived from update.

As for marking Update as abstract on the client, not if you're using an XML based service. On the other end it doesn't see Update as abstract.

Comment: It shouldn't see an Update object at all because you can't instantiate on abstract class. Would it work if the WCF takes the object as an IUpdate?

Comment: That's not how it works. If you've got a method that returns Update, even if Update is abstract, on the other end of an XML service they're going to see Update and be able to create it. These details don't make it across when the client proxy is created.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark all classes with DataContract and all members you want to transmit as DataMember.
Additionally, you have to use the NetDataContract serializer, otherwise you won't be able to transmit class hierarchies or interfaces through WCF.

For an example of using NetDataContractSerializer: [WCF Net Data Contract Serializer](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/08/wcf-using-the-netdatacontractserializer-to-share-your-type/)